# JavaScript Escaping Strings don’t work on Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, firefox, escaping, firefox-developer-tools

While I was trying the escaping strings on Firefox, I noticed that escaping strings don’t work on **Firefox Developer Tools**, unless they are inside a `console.log()` or `alert()` message.

For example, if you just type inside the console the following message:

```
"The man whispered, \"please speak to me.\""
```

the result will be exactly the same with what you typed:

```
"The man whispered, \"please speak to me.\""
```

However, if you include the message in `console.log()`, then it works fine:

Input:

```
console.log("The man whispered, \"please speak to me.\"");
```

Output:

```
The man whispered, "please speak to me."
```

I don't know if it's some kind of bug or there's something deeper I'm not aware of, so I post it here and I hope someone could elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox's Web Console is pulling double duty as a [REPL environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and as the place where `window.console` dumps its output. When you type `'"'` in the Web Console, it reads and evaluates that string as a line of Javascript, and gives you the return value in a form it thinks you can use. Since `'"'` evaluates to a string, Firefox gives you that result as a string literal, `"\""`. But it still only contains one character, U+0022 QUOTATION MARK. You can see this for yourself with further testing:

```
» var str = '"'
⬅ undefined
» str
⬅ "\""
» str.length
⬅ 1
» str.charCodeAt(0)
⬅ 34
```

When you use `console.log()`, on the other hand, the Web Console is dumping the objects given to `console.log` as log messages. Firefox has a different idea of what makes a useful log message: for strings, an easy-to-read message is better than a string literal you could copy back into your code. Thus,

```
» console.log(str)
  "                                     debugger eval code:1:1
⬅ undefined
```

Note the `undefined` at the bottom: the Console is still REPLing. The `"` line is `console.log` intruding on your conversation.